# Find an expression for the common difference in terms of $x$, $y$, and $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The sum of the 1st and 2nd terms of an arithmetic series is $x$ and the sum of the $(n-1)$th and $n$th terms is $y$. Show that the sum of the first $n$ terms is $(n/4)(x+y)$. Find an expression for the common difference in terms of $x$, $y$ and $n$.

I have tried substituting the terms into the expression for the sum of an arithmetic series, then manipulating them and equating them in different ways but I have not got close to an answer for either part of the question.

The answer in the book for the common difference is $\dfrac{y-x}{2(n - 2)}$.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: If the first term is $a$ and the common difference is $d$, then the first two terms are $a$ and $a+d$. Thus $2a+d=x$. The $(n-1)$-th term is $a+(n-2)d$ and the $n$-th is $a+(n-1)d$, so $2a+(2n-3)d=y$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $d$ be the common difference. Then observe that:
$$
x = t_1 + t_2 = t_1 + (t_1 + d) = 2t_1 + d \\
y = t_{n-1} + t_n = (t_n - d) + t_n = 2t_n - d
$$
For the first part, consider adding the two equations then dividing by two. For the second part, consider subtracting the two equations then dividing by two.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the first term and $d$ be the common difference in the series as some initial notes.  We are given the following facts:

$x=a+a+d=2a+d$

$y=a+(n-2)d+a+(n-1)*d = 2a+(2n-3)*d$

Now, if we subtract these formulas, we get the following:

$x-y = d-(2n-3)d$

If you isolate $d$ on one side you should be able to get the common difference so consider this a major hint.  Once this is done, then you could plug that into the initial equations to get the end terms you need in order to compute the overall sum.

Comment: I think maybe you want to change the coefficients for d in your expression for y.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected the coefficients now.

Comment: I have isolated d = (x - y) / (4 - 2n) but how does that help in the initial equations?

Comment: @GezBishop, if you factor the 2 out of the denominator and multiply numerator and denominator by -1 you will get the answer.

Comment: @JB King, thanks, I see that part now. How does the first part of the question work, please? Adding the two expressions gives x + y = 4a + (2n - 2) *d  but I cannot see how to get (n/4)(x + y)

Comment: Remember the formula for the sum of an arithmetic series is the first term plus the nth term times n/2.  Consider that you want 2a+(n-1)*d as the first term plus the nth term which is double the x+y.  Does that help?